# What is the purpose of dotdot in smart home devices?

Tags: smart-home, communication, dotdot

The ZigBee Alliance recently released [dotdot](https://www.speakdotdot.com/dotdot/), a new application layer for Internet of Things devices. They also provide a brief description of what dotdot does:

> dotdot is the universal language of the Internet of Things, making it possible for smart objects to work together on zigbee, IP, and other networks.

After [reading an article about the new protocol](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/01/04/zigbee_announces_dotdot_app_layer/), it turns out that dotdot is just a rebrand/expansion of the [ZigBee Cluster Library](http://www.zigbee.org/download/standards-zigbee-cluster-library/), which comes with an incredibly long specification document (not exactly light reading!). I'm failing to see how this is really much of an improvement over the protocols we have already, since the main site is full of marketing jargon and the specification isn't particularly enlightening.

**Why is *yet another specification* needed in the communications stack of IoT devices, and what benefits can dotdot bring to a typical smart home?**

Comment: [There's always the wisdom of XKCD](https://www.xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: Interoperability, so if you have different smart devices in your home using different non-universal standards, a one standard specification may help make them all compatible, etc.!!